# Python import fails when importing grandchild of parent directory

Tags: python, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I have the following directory structure:

```
C:\project\
|   __init__.py   
│
└───folder1
|   |    __init__.py
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
|       |   __init__.py
│       │   moduleA.py
│       │   moduleB.py
│   
└───folder2
    |   __init__.py
    └───subfolder2
        |   __init__.py
        │   myScript.py
```

In the myScript.py file I want to import classes from moduleA.py. I can successfully import classes from moduleA in the following manner:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('C:/project/folder1')

from subfolder1.moduleA import ClassA
```

However when I attempt to import using the following I get an ImportError "No module named moduleA":

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('C:/project')

from folder1.subfolder1.moduleA import ClassA
```

I've checked permissions on all files in the project/ directory as well as made sure all `__init__.py` files are empty (I copied the `__init__.py` from subfolder1 to all other `__init__.py` locations) and at this point I'm not sure why things are not importing correctly. Current working directory ( verified by `print(os.getcwd())` ) indicates `C:/project/folder2/subfolder2`.

This is using Python 2.7 on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I fixed the issue by inserting my path at the begninning of sys.path rather than appending it. No idea why Python couldn't find the module originally but this fixed it:

`sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/project')`

instead of

`sys.path.append('C:/project')`